# TensorFlow: How to predict from a SavedModel?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have exported a `SavedModel` and now I with to load it back in and make a prediction. It was trained with the following features and labels:

```
F1 : FLOAT32
F2 : FLOAT32
F3 : FLOAT32
L1 : FLOAT32
```

So say I want to feed in the values `20.9, 1.8, 0.9` get a single `FLOAT32` prediction. How do I accomplish this? I have managed to successfully load the model, but I am not sure how to access it to make the prediction call.

```
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(
        sess,
        [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
        "/job/export/Servo/1503723455"
    )

    # How can I predict from here?
    # I want to do something like prediction = model.predict([20.9, 1.8, 0.9])
```

This question is not a duplicate of the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098863). This question focuses on a minimal example of performing inference on a `SavedModel` of any model class (not just limited to `tf.estimator`) and the syntax of specifying input and output node names.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import an saved Tensorflow model train using tf.estimator and predict on input data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098863/how-to-import-an-saved-tensorflow-model-train-using-tf-estimator-and-predict-on)

Comment: See my latest edit about why this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: check detailed answer with tensorflow 1.7 here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52222383/5904928

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once the graph is loaded, it is available in the current context and you can feed input data through it to obtain predictions. Each use-case is rather different, but the addition to your code will look something like this:

```
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(
        sess,
        [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
        "/job/export/Servo/1503723455"
    )

    prediction = sess.run(
        'prefix/predictions/Identity:0',
        feed_dict={
            'Placeholder:0': [20.9],
            'Placeholder_1:0': [1.8],
            'Placeholder_2:0': [0.9]
        }
    )

    print(prediction)
```

Here, you need to know the names of what your prediction inputs will be. If you did not give them a nave in your `serving_fn`, then they default to `Placeholder_n`, where `n` is the nth feature.

The first string argument of `sess.run` is the name of the prediction target. This will vary based on your use case.

Comment: Why can't we pass multiple values to each placeholder, something like a batch or inputs? ```prediction = sess.run(
        'prefix/predictions/Identity:0',
        feed_dict={
            'Placeholder:0': [20.9, 11.3],
            'Placeholder_1:0': [1.8, 2.6],
            'Placeholder_2:0': [0.9, 0.76]
        }
    )```

Answer (score 15):

Assuming you want predictions in Python, [SavedModelPredictor](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/predictor/saved_model_predictor.py) is probably the easiest way to load a SavedModel and get predictions. Suppose you save your model like so:

```
# Build the graph
f1 = tf.placeholder(shape=[], dtype=tf.float32)
f2 = tf.placeholder(shape=[], dtype=tf.float32)
f3 = tf.placeholder(shape=[], dtype=tf.float32)
l1 = tf.placeholder(shape=[], dtype=tf.float32)
output = build_graph(f1, f2, f3, l1)

# Save the model
inputs = {'F1': f1, 'F2': f2, 'F3': f3, 'L1': l1}
outputs = {'output': output_tensor}
tf.contrib.simple_save(sess, export_dir, inputs, outputs)
```

(The inputs can be any shape and don't even have to be placeholders nor root nodes in the graph).

Then, in the Python program that will use the `SavedModel`, we can get predictions like so:

```
from tensorflow.contrib import predictor

predict_fn = predictor.from_saved_model(export_dir)
predictions = predict_fn(
    {"F1": 1.0, "F2": 2.0, "F3": 3.0, "L1": 4.0})
print(predictions)
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46139198/1399222) shows how to get predictions in Java, C++, and Python (despite the fact that the *question* is focused on Estimators, the answer actually applies independently of how the `SavedModel` is created).

Comment: Evidently simple_save does is not compatible with graph building code when inputs to model are being read from input files using tf.data.Dataset and its iterator because simple_save requires tensors not numpy arrays. Furthermore the namespace is changed to tf.saved_model not tf.contrib.  My code might be the problem. A known working code example using model trained using Dataset and saved with simple_save would be excellent to have @mrry.

Comment: Evidently a further incompatibility of simple_save is with graph-making code that inputs sparse numpy arrays, and the first line of graph-making code is a tf.stack because it is a sparse matrix. So where do you put the tf.stack, outside the graph building code? A known working code example using a model calling tf.stack and saved with simple_save would be excellent to have @mrry

Comment: @GeoffreyAnderson Sounds worthy of its own question; be sure to post snippets of the code you are using.

Comment: Just a note that this may no longer work in TensorFlow 2.0. At the very least, the imports may have changed.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who needs a working example of saving a trained canned model and serving it without tensorflow serving ,I have documented here 
https://github.com/tettusud/tensorflow-examples/tree/master/estimators

1. You can create a predictor from `tf.tensorflow.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model( exported_model_path)`
2. Prepare input

   ```
   tf.train.Example( 
       features= tf.train.Features(
           feature={
               'x': tf.train.Feature(
                    float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5])
               )     
           }
       )    
   )
   ```

---

Here `x` is the name of the input that was given in input_receiver_function at the time of exporting.
 for eg:

```
feature_spec = {'x': tf.FixedLenFeature([4],tf.float32)}

def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string,
                                           shape=[None],
                                           name='input_tensors')
    receiver_tensors = {'inputs': serialized_tf_example}
    features = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_spec)
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of `tf.estimator.DNNClassifier` has an argument called `warm_start_from`. You can give it the `SavedModel` folder name and it will recover your session.

Comment: The `warm_start_from` folder contains checkpoint or `SavedModel`? They are not the same.